# apache2 not reachable on his IP from outside

Tags: networking, apache2

my webserver runs ~ok, I can see that at least locally apache2 is responding to localhost and http://192.168.0.1 but if I try from another machine in the same subnet I can't see it. Of course I can ping/ssh the webserver and firewall is disabled. From the server if I try:

```
netstat -an | grep :80
```

I get:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

and my /etc/hosts just contains:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

and I have a standard apache2.conf file. What can be wrong?